# Typescript generics, check value type for given key of generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function `sortData` that takes in a key and sorts an array of objects by the values for that key:

```
function compare(v1: string | number, v2: string | number) {
  return (v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0);
}    

function sortData<T>(data: Array<T>, column: keyof T, direction: string): Array<T> {
  if (direction === '' || column === '') {
    return data;
  } else {
    return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
      const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
      return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the type of `data[0][column]`, which is a value in an object of type `T`, might not be a `string | number` that I can legally pass to the `compare` function.  `T` might have `string | number` type values, or it might have other stuff, I don't know what is in `T` a priori.  However, I would like for the compiler to complain if I try to call `sortData` with a `column` that does not have a `string | number` value.

How do I check the type of a generic object's value in this case?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxk37N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You can have a utility to get the keys of a type that only have string or number values: https://tsplay.dev/N5ALoN

Comment: @jcalz this does seem to do the trick.  I wrote a test case for your example [here](https://tsplay.dev/ND8R1N) if you'd like to use it in your answer.

Comment: @pink it looks like jcalz's solution is pretty similar.

Comment: The only difference is the error message. They both work. jcalz's errors at the `data` argument; mine errors at the `column` argument.

Comment: @pink's addition is to constrain `K` further so that you get an error on `column` instead of `data` when you call the wrong thing.  I can mention that approach too in my answer although I don't want to step on any toes (edit: yeah, that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I usually take here is to add another [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K` corresponding to the key of `T` you're passing in, and then [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)  `T` to be assignable to a type with a `string | number` property at key `K`; that is, `Record<K, string | number>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```
function sortData<T extends Record<K, string | number>, K extends keyof T>(
    data: Array<T>, column: K, direction: string): Array<T> {
    if (direction === '' || column === '') {
        return data;
    } else {
        return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
            const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
            return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
        });
    }
}
```

That compiles without error now, without changing the desired call-side behavior:

```
interface MyType {
    foo: number, //sortable
    bar: { x: number, y: number } //not sortable
}
var x: MyType[] = [
    { foo: 5, bar: { x: 1, y: 2 } },
    { foo: 3, bar: { x: 3, y: 2 } }
]
console.log(sortData(x, "foo", 'asc')) // okay
console.log(sortData(x, 'bar', 'asc')) // error!
// ----------------> ~
// Argument of type 'MyType[]' is not assignable to parameter 
// of type 'Record<"bar", string | number>[]'.
```

Well, maybe the error message is a little weird, since it complains about the array and not the column.

---

You can change this by constraining `column` to be just those keys of `T` which have a `string` or `number` property, by introducing a utility type involving [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to do the filtering.  Here's one way to write it:

```
type StrNumKeys<T> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string | number ? K : never]: any
}
```

This uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter out the inappropriate keys.  There are various ways other to write `StrNumKeys` which have various edge cases, but I won't belabor the point here.  Anyway, let's just test it for your `MyType` type:

```
type Test = StrNumKeys<MyType>;
// type Test = "foo"
```

That looks right.  So if we use that, we don't even need `column` to be generic:

```
function sortData<T extends Record<StrNumKeys<T>, string | number>>(
    data: Array<T>, column: StrNumKeys<T>, direction: string): Array<T> {
    if (direction === '' || column === '') {
        return data;
    } else {
        return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
            const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
            return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
        });
    }
}
```

That also compiles because `a[column]` is seen as indexing into `Record<StrNumKeys<T>, string | number>` with a key of type `StrNumKeys<T>`, and the compiler is able to see that as assignable to `string | number`.  And now when you call the function you get better errors for bad cases:

```
console.log(sortData(x, "foo", 'asc')); // okay
console.log(sortData(x, 'bar', 'asc')); // error
// -------------------> ~~~~~
// Argument of type '"bar"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"foo"'.
```

---

It's up to you which of those to use; the two-generic version uses more traditional and straightforward TypeScript features, while the single-generic version needs to use conditional types in a somewhat more complicated way.  If the latter version does weird things in edge cases that you can't understand, then you might want to fall back to the former.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVA7gewOIWBATgJbxRIDeAUEtUgGYCuw8ALoRsEvBmHPhABQA3AIwAuJFGZFgAcyQAfJMHpgARgQA0SQQCZxk6XMXK1BAJTkqNa32b18HIcKQAebTqQB+JAFpn4kSQAPncvJH8kAAYzAG4ragBfCni6RhY2DigMfGYAERBmEBcUJAgAD2ZcABNSACUILnwqlwBpLQNCWQUlFXV8IK0W0orq0gBrCABPDFpUIP4U6yqCkHEAQXx8EEnigc4MABsVYHE2pCrCPnT2fSlOmTN1ze3dy2trQln+C6vWdiQALxApAAchBCkUXCOYA4QIBoJBFko7xRSFs9g4y0KcVRSASpQOUGQyNxNHRDiQAG0AHS0rEgAC61KyOX4-BAWlUFgBIRJpPeXGAkjR0EB+x4ID47MpUOODM5MsOctii35IrsFJ+DT+sOBIJAUHg4O8fFI4h8ppxaoSKtxSWsSRSnUq+FoCGQAFlJihJjBiarqLQMBhxCY+loAPQRlmFVQHCABpCqSXiMhIMqh3qaJCTTOmfB4pBR4AYZgSbKx+Mpe00QSS9PiL0+v2UhliymJtNBkNIACsnJT5Ab4S0uaQHnxCQ0nbowfEAGYB-hU8PFznxBO8SkGSlBVl49SDhgZPwY-lCvwyloAETd69afWGxEWKNIDBjba79j7iCH4+nitzxAS8H2TfAQQfA0jTMF8I1KTZsgAQhSV8fDQ9CMMwnwQgAPxQuCNhkFRcDLGYkGYX1kBBJtKNbcFCFIEsywNKBCBkUA42QZgMCQXhwAgF0kHwt9Zgov1QXqRpmmvMD7wkO4umMLN+jo6lkkdUBIFgd0kAAYW-KQQE6CAqhaKZSD5VImB1cVeAEERbkMbow2zXRHPuZzlKRRNyUcQI3F0MI-CQAJnBCQLvAiaIrUSZJrDE5AAGUpAAORUMzJigV54QmaZZks6xKSGTokFysiSgNVAirbcpKmAGp5KcpT8zCIZQwgQQCAZcQQGASZqzimgEtQaAy3hZL8DSsAMqymi-SCGKizg4aUFGsVb2Da9BsDNIbLPFZimGOqGsk7JmgmqaZt2doFKMHp8yCeZE3pJ4th2FA9llGFxAu9LzOu85Lm1DJ3NkR4kA2N7XgKmhPiQb4geuXV4TBCF9mhZGEW8tV1Qxc4VkWh0CSJN41V8qlaWpekmRjNkOSTbleUTXE9zLU0xS4CUpRARUMflJNeeVQmyYEvGtSRwE9Sg40RTNXxLWZmgbWF2KHW2pBnQIN1ECQOb-Vxbs83DJaYxATjEzAlcM3u42xxcgt8WLUtyxyM2qzVlI6wLa29dbdsuznPslyt8RhFHDdCynIdDaQNdLaHa21zHTcEh3L8hUOX8jxPfaLyvJANowOTH2g2IlrfD9+usPdM7-HPAJWEDQTAiDQWlmCYnLgh8GyYSsP7rDcJw4e8OsV9COI4BSNEyjQRkyVr3oxjnZYtiOPjcieL4yBBLI4aQULxe1PUoA)